# Get device resolution from a ScheduledTaskAgent

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get a WP8 device resolution from a ScheduledTaskAgent? How? I was getting the screen size doing

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth
```

but this is not possible in a ScheduledTaskAgent... any alternative or do I have to save this in IsolatedStorage and retrieve when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to register a ScheduledTaskAgent the user needs to run your app. So when your app starts, get the resolution, save it somewhere (like IsolatedStorageSettings) and then read it in the ScheduledTaskAgent.

Comment: I did not know about IsolatedStorageSettings... thanks for the tip, it works perfectly!